# How to include .NET framework library in executable

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2010

I've recently made a Windows Forms Application in VS 2010 Express. When running on my machine it works fine but on other machines it needs to install the .NET framework first. Is there anyway around this? By including the library in my executable? By not using the .NET framework?

I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

Typically this kind of problem would be handled by your Windows Forms Application's installation package.

Opinions vary but I'd suggest the safest/most polite thing to do is to treat .NET as a prerequisite.  If .NET is not present, display a message that it is required before the install will succeed and perhaps point to a Microsoft download page like [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa496123.aspx) or [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek.aspx).  The risk is that you point them to an obsolete download page or that the page moves and invalidates your link.

That said, I would have expected most machines to have some version of the .NET Framework installed (by Windows Update for example) so it's a bit surprising that you're being told it needs to be installed.

I suggest you follow the instructions in [How to: Determine Which .NET Framework Versions Are Installed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568.aspx) to check one of your failing machines to confirm that .NET is not installed (*very* unlikely) or to determine which version (or versions) of .NET is (are) installed.

**Update 6/21/2015** From the comment below, we have evidence of two systems without .NET installed so my "*very* unlikely" comment above is a bit off base!

**Update 7/4/2015**  I have a bad habit of forgetting that not everyone configures their Windows systems exactly the same way I configure mine.  From [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/12/09/the-net-framework-4-5-1-is-now-available-on-windows-update-and-wsus.aspx) it seems that the .NET Framework is 'only' a Recommended Update.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was not aware the .NET  framework was installed by Windows Update. The 2 machines I tested my program on did not have the .NET framework installed. After installing the .NET framework on both of them with Windows Update, my program worked perfectly. Thank you again for your answer.

Comment: Just for my own curiosity, can I ask which OS version those two machines are running?

Comment: The one I made the application on is using Windows 7 SP1 x64-bit and the other one is a VM with Windows 7 SP1 x64-bit

Comment: Windows 7 does come with. NET, but only up to 3.5. Updates will install 4.0 if they're let run